Why would anyone use `\obeyedline`, what meaning should it have in the latest textlive distirbution?
Can anyone check with a grep (sorry I am on windows) what packages use obeyedline? I picked up a strange bug with l3doc and some code of mine which I cannot provide a minimal, as the code is really long. But I see the version of l3doc on ctan uses it at the point where the @@ replacements take place. On my system here I get the meaning of obeyedline as \par! Now which par is this is hard t tell, with the hooks. The obeyedline had a few revisions  in source2e. Can we not get rid of it? Thanks
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ttfamily
\meaning\obeyedline

\meaning\obeylines


\ExplSyntaxOn
test\obeyedline \token_to_str:N \obeyedline
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


\obeyedline is for example used in +v-type argument between lines.  And yes the default definition is \par. You should provide at least the error message, and try to make an example. As it is your question is not understandable. (And as side note: I can use grep also on windows.)

@UlrikeFischer  Thanks. I managed to trace the error and thanks for the grep as well.

I'm not 100% sure I really see what the question is here: do you want to have a  pointer to the docs for \obeyedline, a narrative answer explaining why it was introduced, a fix for some specific issue?

@JosephWright I found the documentation in sourc2e. I am curious to read a narrative as to why it was introduced; my understanding is that with the new hooks it relates to the way  obeylines are defined. I also found it strange that if its current meaning is par   why it named as \obeyedline!

@yannisl There's no link to hooks - but I've tried to answer what there is

The \obeyedline command was introduced to allow abstraction in handling of grabbed verbatim lines when creating a document command using \NewDocumentCommand or similar and the +v-type argument. In the earlier implementation, something like
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{+v}{\showtokens{#1}}
\foo|stuff
more stuff
more stuff|

would tokenize the end-of-lines as category-code 12 ^^M. That's then quite awkward to adjust later - you are stuck with needing low-level code.
In the updated approach, the end-of-lines are tokenized as the command \obeyedline. That starts off defined as \par, so if you simply typeset the material you get verbatim output but easy-to-handle line printing. However, if you need something different, all you have to do is locally redefine \obeyedline, e.g. to print a literal newline if writing to a file. That is a lot easier on balance even though it was  breaking change from the original idea.

Thanks Joseph, what led me to it was some code I had that was based on a n older version of l3doc. Similar to this \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_tmpa_tl{test ^^I} \tl_remove_all:Ne \l_@@_tmpa_tl           { \token_to_str:N ^^I \c_space_tl \c_percent_str }   but using ^^M it led to errors. I fixed it changing the ^^M to obeyedline.

@yannisl That’s what I meant about breaking changes: this sort of code does have to be updated

Since when is this? Is it a recent change?

@JasperHabicht 2024-06-01 release

Got me into some trouble, but once I found where the problem was (which took quite a while), the issue was easy to solve thanks to this answer.
